# Table inside div overflow scroll block

Tags: php, css, html, overflow

I have a loop records grab from database, I tried to put these records into a div block with overflow to allow user to scroll through a long list for each, somehow when I display below code, the div block are looks disorder without scroll, how can I put table inside div block with overflow?

```
<div style="overflow:auto;height:100px;width:358px;">
    <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td><input id="" class="" name="ids[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $user_email; ?>" /></td>
            <td><?php echo $user_name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user_email; ?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php
        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM sub_user where parent_user_id=".$row['user_id'];
        $result2 = mysql_query($query2);

        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
            $user_name = stripslashes($row2['user_name']);
            $su_position = stripslashes($row2['su_position']);
            $su_telephone = stripslashes($row2['su_telephone']);
            $user_email = stripslashes($row2['user_email']);
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td><input id="" class="" name="ids[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $user_email; ?>" /></td>
            <td><?php echo $user_name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user_email; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Please advise. thanks.

Comment: I think your code is working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/kF4DL/

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but unless your data is corrupted, you should *not* use `stripslashes` when you read data out from mysql, even if you had used `addslashes` on input.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll;height:100px;width:358px">
<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="" class="" name="ids[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $user_email; ?>" /></td>
        <td><?php echo $user_name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user_email; ?></td>

    </tr>

    <?php
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM sub_user where parent_user_id=".$row['user_id'];
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);

    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
        $user_name = stripslashes($row2['user_name']);
        $su_position = stripslashes($row2['su_position']);
        $su_telephone = stripslashes($row2['su_telephone']);
        $user_email = stripslashes($row2['user_email']);
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td><input id="" class="" name="ids[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $user_email; ?>" /></td>
        <td><?php echo $user_name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user_email; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```